# CMD - Batch - HTA

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hta

I am really new to coding (I started around 3 weeks back) I have found Robocopy and have written a really simple batch file that basically copies a folder from a master directory and then pastes in into a sub folder in 2 destinations that I have specify when I launch the batch file.

This looks messy and I have been trying HTAs and trying to get it so that I can type the variable into the HTA and then that do everything else for me. I was thinking this would just look nicer than a CMD window.

I have got the HTA in a simple version that I will style later but I just cannot figure out how to pass the variable into the batch file or if there is a better way to do this. I have read through so many posts on this, but they all seem far more complex than what I need and ultimately I am failing.

My batch file is currently

```
    CODE:

    set /p dest=Please enter destination: 
    robocopy "D:\MasterFolder\- Details" "E:\Sets\%dest%" /E /V /NP /R:10 /W:30 
    robocopy "D:\MasterFolder\- Details" "F:\%dest%" /E /V /NP /R:10 /W:30
```

This does work well but just isn't very nice to look at, I was hoping that with a HTA I could get away from the first line and have that input in a GUI. So far I have managed to come up with the following I just need some help to get this to take the variable from the HTA and place this into the batch file. Or some guidance if there is a better way that this can be achieved

```
<head>
<title>Folder Creator</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION 
APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Folder Creator"
SCROLL="no"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
WINDOWSTATE="normal"
>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.resizeTo(400,200);
</script>

<body>
<label for="dest">Destination:</label>
<input type="text" id="dest">
<br><br>
<button onclick="closeHTA(true);">Create</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread to make an idea about [Using "HTA input forms" in Batch files](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6581)

Comment: @Hackoo What!? Where's the code bunch  = ).

Comment: @Teemu I post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to take a variable from HTA to batch script :
***Reply_from_HTA.bat***

```bat
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
Title Pass variable from HTA to batch
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply from HTA GUI : "%HTAreply%"
Set "dest=%HTAreply%"
echo robocopy "D:\MasterFolder\- Details" "E:\Sets\%dest%" /E /V /NP /R:10 /W:30 
echo robocopy "D:\MasterFolder\- Details" "F:\%dest%" /E /V /NP /R:10 /W:30 
pause>nul
goto :EOF
-->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >
<TITLE>HTA GUI Form</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="Vbscript">
Sub window_onload()
       CenterWindow 200,150
       Focus
End Sub

Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
        window.resizeTo x, y
        iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
        itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
        window.moveTo ileft, itop
End Sub

Function closeHTA(reply)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply)
   window.close()
End Function

Sub Focus()
    txt.Focus
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<label for="dest">Please enter destination</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<br><Input type="Submit" onclick="closeHTA(txt.value)" value="Submit"> 
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: thank you, i will look at working this into this tomorrow